# Django ModelForm not rendering in the template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've looked at several answers here and I can't get this to work. I'm trying to create a model form that will save the user's profile after he has signed up on the website. The problem is that when I try to render the form I get a blank page and no errors. Any help will be much appreciated.

models.py

```
class Perfil(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    Sexo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CP = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Estado = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Pais = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Telefono = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Celular = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    PaisPasaporte = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    NumeroPasaporte = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    VigenciaPasaporte = models.DateField(max_length=100)
    ContactoEmergencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    TelefonoEmergencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    CorreoEmergencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Alergias = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
```

views.py

```
@verified_email_required()
def profile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            perfil = form.save(commit=False)
            perfil.user = request.user
            perfil.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/profile/")
        else:
            return render(request, "explore/profile.html", {"form": form})
    return render(request, "explore/profile.html")
```

and finally my html

```
<form class="profile" id="profile_form" method="post" action="" style="width: 50%;">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    <table>
                    <colgroup>
                        <col style="width: 45%;">
                        <col style="width: 10%;">
                        <col style="width: 45%;">
                    </colgroup>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ field.label_tag }}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{ field }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                {% endfor %}
            </form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are sending the form in the context **only** when request type is `POST`. The first time the page loads, by default it is a `GET` request. Hence the issue

Something like this should work:

```
def profile(request):
    form = ProfileForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            perfil = form.save(commit=False)
            perfil.user = request.user
            perfil.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/profile/")

    return render(request, "explore/profile.html" {'form': form})
```

Note that you dont need the `else` clause at all - if the form is invalid, it automatically sends the erroneous form in the context, and your error messages are displayed just fine.

Comment: comma missing in return